# Is this "Fae Ancestry" homebrew sorcerer subclass balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, sorcerer, archetype, homebrew-review

Continuing my current planar obsession I have made this Fae Ancestry sorcerer subclass. To me (I may be biased), it looks mostly fine except for Fae Charm, but I can't tell which is the reason I am asking this question.

> ## Fae Ancestry
>
> ### Fae Speech
>
> You can speak, read, and write Sylvan. In addition, you can
> communicate with beasts that are charmed by you as if you shared a
> language.
>
> ### Faerie Magic
>
> When your Spellcasting feature lets you learn or replace a sorcerer
> cantrip or a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher, you can choose the
> new spell from the bard spell list or the sorcerer spell list. You
> must otherwise obey all restrictions for selecting the spell, and it
> becomes a sorcerer spell for you if it is not already.
>
> ### Defensive Glamour
>
> Starting at 6th level, you can turn invisible in response to danger.
> When a creature makes an attack roll against you, you can use your
> reaction to turn invisible and cause the attack to miss you. This
> invisibility lasts until the start of your next turn. Once you use
> this feature, you can't use it again until you finish a long rest.
>
> ### Fae Walk
>
> At 14th level, you can spend 2 sorcery points as a bonus action to
> magically teleport up to 120 feet away to an unoccupied space you can
> see.
>
> ### Fae Charm
>
> Beginning at 18th level, you can use an action to spend 5 sorcery
> points and force one non-fey creature within 60 feet of you to make a
> Wisdom saving throw or be charmed by you. While charmed in this way,
> the creature treats you with reverence and will do as you ask as long
> as it is not harmful to the target creature. A creature with an
> Intelligence of 11 or more can repeat this save once every 24 hours,
> until it breaks free. Otherwise, the charm lasts until you dismiss it
> as an action, a Remove Curse spell is cast on the target, or once 7
> days have passed. Once a creature passes its saving throw or the
> effect ends on it, you can't use this feature on that creature again.

Is this subclass balanced?

Comment: The druid spell list might be more in-theme than the bard spell list.

Comment: @BenjaminHubbard I agree. Besides, the bard's whole theme revolves around having a unique spell list and being able to borrow minimally from other classes'. Simply giving access to every bard spell to sorcerer (or any class, for that matter), while definitely not overpowered, removes a lot from bard's uniqueness as a class.

Comment: @BenjaminHubbard You're probably right. I'll change that in the finished version.

Comment: Check out [existing homebrew options](https://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew/subclasses?filter-name=fey&filter-author=&filter-author-previous=&filter-author-symbol=&filter-parent-class=6&filter-rating=-26&sort=rating).

Comment: I've voted to reopen this because the target has been deleted, so the closure doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think **Fae Charm** is absolutely overpowered. At the level 18, if you use [Font of Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#FontofMagic-371) to turn all your spell slots into sorcery points, you end up with 94 sorcery points, which is enough to use this ability 18 times between long rests.

Taking into account, that there are no restrictions of how many creatures can be charmed at a time, their kind (non-fey is hardly a restriction) and incredible duration, you can easily get an army of dragons, if only you find enough of them.

Other abilities might be even underpowered compared to other sorcerous origins. For instance, **Fae Speech** is not much better than an additional language, which is cheap, and communicating with beasts can be achieved by a [1st level spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/speak-with-animals), that can be cast as a ritual and does not have a restriction that the animal must be charmed by you, not to mention it is very situational. I'm not saying it's a bad thing to have (both in terms of usefulness and flavour), but I would remove the requirement, that the beast must be charmed and add another minor trait at the 1st level on top.

**Defensive Glamour** is generally fine, but it's not quite clear from the logical point of view, how turning invisible would cause an attack to miss you, normally it would only impose disadvantage. I would change it to blinking onto the Ethereal Plane till the start of your next turn, so you virtually disappear from the Material Plane, which would only add more flavour to this sorcerous origin.

**Fae Walk** is definitely an underpowered option. This is basically 2nd level [Misty Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) on steroids (120 instead of 30 feet), that doesn't make it much more useful, and you still need to spend sorcery points on it, and it's only 1.5 times cheaper (one can turn 3 sorcery points into one 2-level spell slot). Having in mind, that there are no offensive options at mid-levels, I would replace it with something more offensive and versatile, like special [Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph)-like abilities (but maybe more powerful).

Comment: You would be better placed comparing Fae Walk to the Shadow Sorcerer's Shadow Walk, which is significantly more powerful

Comment: @illustro Shadow Walk doesn't require any sorcery points to be spent. Other than that, I don't see how it's significantly more powerful than Misty Step.

Comment: @codeholic it's got a longer range, doesn't require any sorcery points to be spent and only costs a bonus action. Shadow Walk can be performed indefinitely whereas Fae Walk cannot.

Comment: @illustro I don't see how it contradicts what I said. Casting time of Misty Step is also a bonus action.

Comment: It doesn't. I'm saying comparing it to Shadow Walk gives you a stronger argument than comparing it to Misty Step

Comment: @illustro Okay, agreed.

Answer (score 3):

First, a quick consistency thing making me twitch, D&D 5e convention and monster types would call them "Fey", and would call  something like "Fey Touched Sorcerous Origin". Now on with the reading...

> Beginning at 18th level you can use an action to spend 5 sorcery points and force one non-fey creature within 60 feet of you to make a Wisdom saving throw or be charmed by you.

This is similar to [*suggestion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/suggestion) so far. Except the long duration, and that being a class Feature, and not a spell, it can't be dispelled with [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic). It doesn't require concentration, which if you really want it to last 7 days makes sense because you have to sleep, but allows you to create an army of charmed people who do things for you for 7 days..

This is free gold, materials and crafted items.  They do whatever you suggest as long as you don't harm them, means that you could have them sign over all their property, if they are skilled in making magic items they can make you magic items, etc. etc.  With 7 days of control, you can leave and have days lead on them so you never feel the consequences of your actions.  This is looking to Munchkined and rife to start a lot of player problems.

Comment: then again, by level 18, ninth level spell are alive and well ... but I still think you make a good  point.